# How can I consume a SQL database to create / update records in salesforce using apex?

Tags: apex, integration, account, sql, database

I would like to consult you for something, do you know if it is possible that a sql database can be consumed from salesforce?
What happens is that account records are loaded into the SQL database and a code is generated, so what I am looking for is that every month salesforce consult this database to verify that these accounts exist in salesforce and if not then create or update these records in salesforce.

Is it possible to get to this using apex?

I really appreciate your support.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of approaches available.

One is to expose the SQL data as an External Object where the data can then be queried using Apex's SOQL calls.

Too big a subject to document in an answer here so Google and see e.g. [Configuring an External Data Source and External Objects](https://developerforce.github.io/lightning-connect-tutorial/configure-data-source-objects.html).